# How to handle "header file not found" for a podfile library? ('XYZ.h' file not found) - In Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, cocoapods, podfile

I already had installed my pod files and they were working fine, but after pulling from orignin/main this error showed up. And I also had put all the pod files and their related files to .gitignore so I'm not sure whether the pulling caused this problem or not...
[image]

so far I've deleted my derieved data and updated my pods via the pod update command, but it didn't do any good...

Answer (score 2):

I followed the following steps and it solved the problem:

1. remove Derived Data for the related project
2. pod deintegrate
3. pod cache clean --all
4. cmd+q XCode
5. pod install
6. run & build!

To find the Derived Data folder you can choose Xcode tab from the top bar menu and then choose settings. Within the setting window, find the Derived Data section and you can both see the directory path and click on the arrow to open the finder...
[image]